# How to create a svn branch from local git branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

I am using git version 1.7.2.3 and I have the following situation:

```
  Clone git repo from svn
  |
  *
  * (<= commits to master & corresponding commit to svn)
  *
  *
  |
  master (points to svn HEAD)
  |
  |___ my-branch (no equivalent svn branch)
        |
        *
        * (multiple commits to this branch)
        *
        *
        |
        (Current head of my-branch)
```

I would like to know how to push the "`Current head of my-branch`" branch in git on to svn (where it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: kind of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490794/git-svn-create-push-a-new-branch-tag, no?

Comment: kind of similar but the difference is in the detail I missed out. When the original clone was created I did not do the shallow copy using the -s flag. I just cloned the trunk. Because of this the config file does not have any clue about the Branches/Tags.

Comment: I could only think of a round about solution: 1) do another clone with the -s flag. 2) Follow the steps outlined here: http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial#TrackingSVNbrancheswithGIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to just check out the subversion repository again this time with the previously omitted -s flag. First create a patch on your already set up git repo:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git format-patch master --stdout > my_branch.patch
```

Then apply the patch (git apply) on your newly created git repository which is aware of the tags and branches directory of subversion. For that `git svn branch` will do the job.

Comment: Instead of a manual merge, the patch would have worked easily. Thanks for your answer.