# Create an SVN branch from an existing Git branch

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-branch

I have cloned an existing SVN project via `git svn clone` with no problem so far, but in the mean time I have created a branch in Git only (not in SVN) and now i would like to synchronize this branch back to an SVN branch (not the trunk).

I have created the branch a little time ago. Is it possible to get back the information stored on that Git branch into SVN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new branch in Subversion using `git svn branch`.  You might want to look at the example in this answer:

- [Git-svn: create & push a new branch/tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490794/git-svn-create-push-a-new-branch-tag/2524745#2524745)

In particular, a good tip in the linked tutorial is to use the `--dry-run` option to `svn dcommit` to check that when you run the command for real, it'll be pushing to the right branch.

The Pro Git book has [a clearer description](http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html#subversion_branching) of how `git svn dcommit` decides which svn branch to update.  It sounds to me as if you should:

- Create a new svn branch using `git svn branch new-experiment`
- Create a local branch to track `remotes/new-experiment` with `git checkout --track -b new-experiment remotes/new-experiment`
- Rebase the changes from your old git topic branch (let's suppose it's called `experiment`) onto `new-experiment`:

  ```
   git checkout experiment
   git branch original-experiment
   git rebase new-experiment
   git checkout new-experiment
   git merge experiment
  ```
- Try `git svn dcommit --dry-run` to check that the right subversion branch will be updated
- If so, do `git svn dcommit`

Comment: I want to commit the changes i made on the Git branch into a Subversion branch and NOT to the trunk. If i would like to get those changes to the trunk i can simply do a merge before.

Comment: That wasn't at all clear from your question.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @khmarbaise: OK, I've finished updating my answer now - I hope that's more clear.  I'm suggesting rebasing rather than merging so that you don't just end up with one merge commit in your subversion branch.

Comment: I got the error `'remotes/my-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'my-branch' cannot be created from it.` I had to do `git branch -r` to see the actual name.