# git svn master to branch to master - still tries to commit to branch

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490794/git-svn-create-push-a-new-branch-tag) post on how to create and checkout a branch using git svn so that the branch was actually created on the svn repos.  This worked great.

When I was done with my branch, I did a checkout on master and did a git merge.  This worked fine.  I then went to commit the merge back to the trunk on the svn repos so issues a git svn dcommit.

And it tried to commit to the branch.  Even though I now have the master branch checked out.  What am I missing?

```
$ git svn branch -m "test branch" test_branch
$ git checkout --track -b test_branch remotes/test_branch
$ Hack hack hack...
$ git svn dcommit --dry-run    # Make sure you're committing to the right SVN branch
$ git svn dcommit              # Commit changes to "test_branch" branch in SVN
$ git checkout master
$ git merge test-branch
$ git svn dcommit # why is this committing to the branch instead of trunk??
```

This is my .git/config in case it matters

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = mysvnrepos.com/svn/project
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
[branch "test_branch"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/remotes/test_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought someone asked this already, but I can't find it again. Anyway, git-svn with branches is complicated. You must create empty branches on the svn side, with `git svn branch` or plain `svn mkdir`. Then you check out those branches with git, and rebase commits on top of them without using git-level merges. This way the git branches have the right svn branch indicated in their ancestry, and dcommit commits to the correct branch. You can verify the branch git-svn would commit to using `git svn info`.

Comment: That's all great for the future, but I need to fix what's happening now that I've apparently not done it right.

Comment: @Gregg `git checkout master; git rebase test_branch` will eliminate the merge commit which should restore order.

Comment: It did not.  I did both of those commands, then a git svn dcommit --dry-run.  Still says it is Committing to my branch.

Comment: `rm .git/svn/refs/trunk/.rev_map.*` and try again?

Comment: No go.  I'm going to scrap it and start over just so I can keep working.  The branch didn't have much in it because I was just using it to test.  But I'm still very curious of how I might fix this.