# Using git-svn, how do I dcommit tags?

Tags: git, svn, tags, git-svn, tortoisegit

I was using Git to retain a history of my project locally.  I was later asked to commit the entire git project into a remote, empty svn project folder (the usual trunk, tags, branches structure, in that case and spelling).  I was able to commit to the trunk perfectly fine, but none of the tags seemed to have been dcommitted.  Is there a way to commit tags, preferably through a single command?

P.S. I am using TortoiseGit, but command line is fine, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Git and SVN treat tags differently. Tags are a powerful feature in Git, but just a folder in SVN, much like how branches are.

So to create tags in SVN from git-svn, you have to create a branch (tag) in git-svn repo. Git tags will not be "dcommitted"

You can use `git svn branch --tag` or its shorthand `git svn tag` to create tags and then dcommit them.

Related question with detailed answer: [Git-svn: create & push a new branch/tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490794/git-svn-create-push-a-new-branch-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sounds like I have to 1) checkout the git tag in my local project, 2) create a remote branch with your answer above, 3) then dcommit, yes?  A bit unfortunate it has to be this complicated, but then again, Git is kind of complicated in comparison to SVN.

Comment: @japtar - Um, Git is not complicated, but you are interacting with two completely different systems. But yeah, git does have a steep learning curve

Comment: I didn't intend to make any snide remark about Git, but if it came out that way, I apologize.  I'm liking it, actually.  It's quite convenient.

Comment: @Japtar - I am an heavy svn and git user and like both. SVN has it's pluses, Git has its pluses. Just that you can't expect git-svn to be not complicated when the two vcs's differ a lot.