# Create an svn tag from an existing git tag

Tags: git, svn, branch, git-svn

I am trying to create a proper SVN tag from an annotated git tag. I presumed that what I have to do is :

- checkout the tag -> done
- **git svn branch -tm "version x"**

Calling the branch command results in the following error message :

```
Unknown option: t
Unknown option: m

git-svn - bidirectional operations between a single Subversion tree and git
Usage: git svn <command> [options] [arguments]

Available commands:
  blame            Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file
                     --git-format
  clone            Initialize and fetch revisions
                     --add-author-from
  ...
```

surprisingly, neither `branch` nor `tag` commands are listed among the available commands. Calling **git svn branch** results in the same help page, without the "Unknown option" part.
I have no idea what is going wrong and how to fix it.

I am using git 1.6.0.2, git-svn 1.6.0.2 with svn 1.6.13

Unfortunately I don't have the rights to update and to check whether it's a version-related issue

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490794/git-svn-create-push-a-new-branch-tag), that the `branch` command was introduced to git-svn in version **1.6.1**. So it is a version issue.